# Deploy TFS files to remote, non-trusted, environment

Tags: deployment, tfs, build

First, I'm a TFS novice.  I have a situation where I'm running TFS, and want to interact with a domain outside our environment.  The destination server environment does not want to establish any trusts due to security\confidentiality reasons.  I was thinking of using a BuildServer or second TFS server in the remote environment to accept the files from the (local) source TFS.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else looking to do this, I found out there is a way to do it, however it's certainly not a plug-n-play.

The steps would be:

1. Using the TFS API, write a solution to watch for check-in actions. When one is found, wait until the action is completed then copy all items to a temporary location.
2. This temporary is actually a secure FTP location that would send the files to the client site.
3. Once on the destination client, a folder watcher scans for changes.
4. When the FTP process is complete, a TFS API solution application call is made to check in the files to the destination TFS.